# IL Emit call a generic type constructor?

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I'm trying to create a new List<> object in a dynamic method using Emit:

```
Type original; // original is a type passed

AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName("CustomAssembly");
AssemblyBuilder assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
ModuleBuilder _moduleBuilder = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("CustomModule");

// - IProxy can be ignored for this example
TypeBuilder typeBuilder = _moduleBuilder.DefineType(original.Name + "Proxy", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class, original, new Type[] { typeof(IProxy) });

// - Getting the type of List<Interceptor>
Type interceptorList = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Interceptor));
// - Setting a 'private List<Interceptor> _interceptors;'
FieldBuilder interceptorField = typeBuilder.DefineField("_interceptors", interceptorList, FieldAttributes.Private);
// - Getting the default constructor 'new List<Interceptor>()'
ConstructorInfo interceptorConstructor = interceptorList.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
// - And the '.Add(Interceptor interceptor)' method
MethodInfo addInterceptor = interceptorList.GetMethod("Add", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(Interceptor) }, null);

foreach (ConstructorInfo constructorInfo in original.GetConstructors())
{
    ConstructorBuilder constructorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, CallingConventions.Standard, parameters);
    ILGenerator ilGen = constructorBuilder.GetILGenerator();
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //[this]

    //These two lines cause an exception when I try to create this custom type        
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, interceptorConstructor); //[new List<Interceptor>();]
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, interceptorField); //[_interceptors = new List<Interceptor>();]

    // - Calling the base constructor
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, constructorInfo);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
}
```

I've checked the code I'm trying to achieve using ILDasm, and these OpCodes seem to be right, so I'm guessing it's something I'm doing wrong when trying to get the constructor of a generic type.

What am I doing wrong, how can I get this working?

**Edit:** The error occurs on this line:

```
// - Type is the custom type created in runtime
Activator.CreateInstance(Type);
```

**Error Message:** An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target.

**Inner Exception:** Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

**Stack Trace:**    at TestObjectProxy..ctor()

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @SLaks Edited with the error message (had a bit of trouble translating, first time seeing this exception).

Comment: Debug it and inspect the `InnerException` property - you'll find more info there.

Comment: @Haney Just did, but found nothing really useful... I also tried creating a single object instead of a list, but I'm getting the same error, so I guess it's unrelated to the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> // - Calling the base constructor
> ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, constructorInfo);
> ```

That's not complete. A base constructor call is a regular call to an instance method of a base class, so you need another `Ldarg_0` before it.